# GeoPandas dissolve only adjacent polygons

Tags: python, geopandas

With GeoPandas I want to do a dissolve for a field but only for the adjacent polygons.

For example, I have the following geodataframe

```
geojson_str = '''{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Parcelas",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "1", "Field1": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 10.0, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 10.0, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "1", "Field1": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 13.39204563499591, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 19.446796849524269, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 19.446796849524269, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "1", "Field1": 4 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 16.784091269991819, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 17.684798147038752, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 17.684798147038752, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "2", "Field1": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 16.784091269991819, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 10.0, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 10.0, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "5", "Field1": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 10.0, 19.446796849524269, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 19.446796849524269, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 19.446796849524269, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "5", "Field1": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 17.684798147038752, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 17.684798147038752, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "5", "Field1": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 16.784091269991819, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
'''
gdf = gpd.read_file(geojson_str, driver='GeoJSON')
```

[image]

I would like to dissolve only the adjacent plots and add the field 'Field1'

[image]

Comment: All of your polygons are connected either one to one or through neighbours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dissolve by group

Explode multipolygons to single part polygons, calculate a cluster id

Join cluster id to the original data, dissolve by group and cluster id:

```
import geopandas as gpd
geojson_str = '''{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Parcelas",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "1", "Field1": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 10.0, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 10.0, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "1", "Field1": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 13.39204563499591, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 19.446796849524269, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 19.446796849524269, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "1", "Field1": 4 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 16.784091269991819, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 17.684798147038752, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 17.684798147038752, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 22.966870879544931, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "2", "Field1": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 16.784091269991819, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 10.0, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 10.0, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "5", "Field1": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 10.0, 19.446796849524269, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 19.446796849524269, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 19.446796849524269, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "5", "Field1": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 17.684798147038752, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 17.684798147038752, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Group": "5", "Field1": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 16.784091269991819, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ], [ 13.39204563499591, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 16.48343543977246, 0.0 ], [ 16.784091269991819, 13.06622583267367, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
'''
gdf = gpd.read_file(geojson_str, driver='GeoJSON')
#gdf.to_file(r"C:\GIS\GIStest\original_gdf.shp")

#Dissolve by group, then explode multipolygons (separate multipolygon parts with the same group attribut) to polygons
clusters = gdf.dissolve(by="Group").explode(index_parts=True).reset_index()[["geometry"]]
clusters["cluster"] = range(clusters.shape[0]) #Create a unique cluster id for each polygon
#clusters.to_file(r"C:\GIS\GIStest\clusters.shp")

#Set the geometry of the original df to representative points to be used in the spatial join.
gdf = gdf.set_geometry(gdf.representative_point())

#Join the Group attribute from the original dataframes to the clusters dataframe. And dissolve by Group and cluster attributes
gdf = clusters.sjoin(gdf, how="inner", predicate="intersects")
gdf = gdf.dissolve(by=["Group", "cluster"], aggfunc={"Field1":"sum"}, as_index=False)
#gdf.to_file(r"C:\GIS\GIStest\dissolved.shp")
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderfull, tranks